I have created a Img component using Vue Js. but Img is not showing
I have created a Img component using Vue Js. and the component is passed to the header file which is in the same directory, the Img component contains a parent div. when i passed the Img component to the Header file the parent div is showing but inside img is not showing. even the path of img is correct and also img is available in the assets folder, when i add the img direct without the img component the img is showing.
This is the Icon Component Code Snippet 
This Is the Header Component Snippet 
<template>
    <div class="icon d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
        <img v-for="image in images" :key="image.src" :src="image.src" :alt="image.alt" class="icon_class" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'IconComponent',
    props: {
        images: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
            default: () => [],
        },
    },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #F0F2F6;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.icon_class {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}
</style><template>
    <div class="icon d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
        <img v-for="image in images" :key="image.src" :src="image.src" :alt="image.alt" class="icon_class" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'IconComponent',
    props: {
        images: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
            default: () => [],
        },
    },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #F0F2F6;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.icon_class {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}
</style>
<template>
    <div class="header_Parent d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="@/assets/icons/header/logo.svg" alt="logo Icon">
        </div>
        <div class="icons_Block d-flex">
            <IconComponent :images="imageUrls" altText="Logo Icon" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import IconComponent from '@/components/layout/iconComponent.vue'


export default {
    name: 'HeaderComponent',
    components: {
        IconComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            imageUrls: [
                { src: '@/assets/icons/header/icon1.svg' },
            ],
        };
    },
};

</script>
<style scoped>
.header_Parent {
    padding: 8px 32px;
}
</style>[and this is snippet of img which is not showing](https://i.sstatic.net/psAdr.jpg)


I see you are using vite, meaning that when you pass an image like that you have to use the URL constructor.
So in your IconComponent you need to have a method that looks something like this:
getImageUrl(image) {
    // or `/src/assets/${path}` if the path is always different
    return new URL(`/src/assets/icons/${icon}`, import.meta.url)
}

and then use it inside your template:
<div class="icon d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
    <img v-for="image in images" :key="image.src" :src="getImageUrl(image.src)" :alt="image.alt" class="icon_class" />
</div>

You can read more here if you want.

ues require img.
for example
//const img = require("@/assets/icons/header/icon1.svg")
//imageUrls: [ { src: img },],

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
